# Split a string - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have mutltistrings like this :

```
string '10<sup>ème</sup><span class="tLost">(-2)</span>' (length=48)

 string '7<sup>ème</sup><span class="tLost">(-2)</span>' (length=47)

string '5<sup>ème</sup><span class="tLost">(-2)</span>' (length=47)

string '2<sup>ème</sup><span class="tLost">(-2)</span>' (length=47)

string '4<sup>ème</sup><span class="tWin">(+1)</span>' (length=46)
```

And I wonder I can explode them in two parts :

```
array(
  [0]=>'10<sup>ème</sup>',
   [1]=>'<span class="tLost">(-2)</span>'
  )
```

I tried this but it didn't work :

```
$position[] = explode("</sup>",$value);
```

Is there any other way ?? Thanks 
Here's apart of the array that I want to transform :

```
  array (size=21)
 0 => 
  array (size=4)
  'Mot Clé' => string 'TEST1' (length=5)
  'Bing' => string '0<sup>ème</sup><span class="tLost">(-1)</span>' (length=47)
  'Google' => string '10<sup>ème</sup><span class="tLost">(-2)</span>' (length=48)
  'Yahoo' => string '=' (length=1)
 1 => 
array (size=4)
  'Mot Clé' => string 'TEST2' (length=5)
  'Bing' => string '0<sup>ème</sup><span class="tLost">(-1)</span>' (length=47)
  'Google.fr France' => string '7<sup>ème</sup><span class="tLost">(-2)</span>'      (length=47)
    'Yahoo' => string '=' (length=1)
  2 => 
  array (size=4)
  'Mot Clé' => string 'TEST3' (length=5)
  'Bing' => string '0<sup>ème</sup><span class="tLost">(-1)</span>' (length=47)
  'Google' => string '5<sup>ème</sup><span class="tLost">(-2)</span>' (length=47)
  'Yahoo' => string '=' (length=1)
```

Comment: Provide the complete script that demonstrates it

Comment: I don't see the php script. I see some output that php script generates. Just a dummy script that declares hardcoded array/strings and behaves incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this regex... get all tags and put in an array

```
$str = '10<sup>ème</sup><span class="tLost">(-2)</span>';

$arr = array();

preg_match_all('#<.[^<]+>.+?</.[^<]*>#', $str, $arr);
```

the output is

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "<sup>ème</sup>"
    [1]=>
    string(31) "<span class="tLost">(-2)</span>"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because explode will remove the pattern.

You can use for example this simple code if you just need to split the string in two parts:

```
$first = substr($var, 0, strpos($var, "<span"));
$second = substr($var, strpos($var, "<span"), strlen($var) - strpos($var, "<span"));
```

where $var should be the string that you want to split.